# How do i make a specific URL point to a specific file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, routes, area

I want to make it possible for me to access my admin page when typing:

www.sitename.com/admin

is this possible in ASP.NET mvc3?

I have decided to go with the area approuch. However it doesnt seem to work quite yet.

Ive created an Admin area and updated the route in the admin area registration. it looks like this:

```
            context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "skylearn.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
```

however it seems that if i go to my url localhost:1337/admin the index file located in my HOME folder serviced by my HomeController wont load. These folders and controllers are also located inside the admin area.

any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You could create an admin "Area" so that all functions of the admin are contained in one section. The area registration would register /admin/{controller}/{action}/{id} as the default route for that area. Your default "Home" controller in the admin Area would service requestes for /admin/ and /admin/home just like the default Home controller would handle requests for / and /home

Comment: Yes but there is already such different areas. i want the admin page to be located by itself though

Comment: You can create custom routes in your global.asax to map requests for different URLs under the /admin/* path to different controlls/actions if you absoutley have to. I would highly suggest refactoring your code to create an Area ( See http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/aspnet-mvc-2-areas ) and placing all related administrative functions inside of the admin Area. This will create a logical segmentation of function on your site.

Comment: ive actually decided to go with the area approach. but it doesnt seem to work even after i created the area like he did in his video

Comment: please be more specific. You'll have to tell us what doesn't work. There is an AreaRegistration file that gets created in your Area folder, ex: AdminAreaRegistration. It has code to register a route that services your area: context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                , new string[] { "MyWeb.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );

Comment: im sorry i will have to look into this by reading some articles. there is no reason you waste your time trying to guess what my problem is. thank you for the good suggestions and answers

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it by registering a new route just for that URL

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin", // Route name
            "Admin", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "SomeAction" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: you add this to the global.asax file

Comment: If the default route still exists in the application, this route will have little to no impact. The only thing it is doing is changing the default "action" for the admin section. If a path such as /admin/test were to be run, this route would not match and the default route would match, because the "Admin" controller exists and it would look for an action named "test". If by chance the controller AronChan wishes to route his requests to is not called "Admin" then your route would work but I would highly suggest that you include the {action} in your route so you can access other actions.

Comment: If you added {controller} wouldn't you have to add a default action for each one?

Comment: Typo, I had {controller} when it should have been {action}, I updated it

Comment: I agree that it would be a good idea to add {action}.  However, in the post he mentions pointing to a specific file, which made me think he only cares about point to one action.